# Can't acces object within array

Tags: typescript

I can't assign a specific object to a variable, although the type is the Right. I have a class called Article.

```
export class Article {

    skuNumber: number;
    condition: string;
    eanCode: number;
    manufacturer: string;
    manufacturerIdentifier: string;
    title: string;
    description: string;
    quantity: number;
    weight: number;
    width: number;
    height: number;
    depth: number 

    constructor(
        skuNumber: number, 
        condition: string,
        eanCode: number,
        manufacturer: string,
        manufacturerIdentifier: string,
        title: string,
        description: string,
        quantity: number,
        weight: number,
        width: number,
        height: number,
        depth: number
    ) {
        this.skuNumber = skuNumber;
        this.condition = condition;
        this.eanCode = eanCode;
        this.manufacturer = manufacturer;
        this.manufacturerIdentifier = manufacturerIdentifier;
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.width = width
        this.height = height;
        this.depth = depth
    }
}
```

In another file I populated an Array with some sample data:

```
import { Article } from "./article";

export const ARTICLES: Array<Article> = [
    new Article(
        1, 
        'used', 
        5060639120949, 
        'Monster Energy', 
        'NLZ0930EG', 
        'Espresso Monster Vanilla + Espresso',
        'Ein Espressomischgetränk mit Taurin, Milch und Vanilla-Flavour.',
        12,
        0.2,
        8,
        15,
        8
    ),
    new Article(
        2, 
        'used', 
        4018931180179, 
        'G Data', 
        'NLZ0930EG', 
        'G Data Inernet Secuirty Lizenzurkunde',
        'Lizenzurkunde der Vollversion von G Data Internet Security.',
        2,
        0.2,
        8,
        15,
        0
    ),
    new Article(
        3, 
        'used', 
        4101090000638, 
        'Staatl. Fachingen', 
        'NLZ0930EG', 
        'Mineralwasser Medium',
        'Mineralwasser Medium feinperlend und erfrischend.',
        57,
        1,
        10,
        25,
        10
    )
];
```

Now I want to search a specific object within this Array by

```
let article: Article = this.articles.filter(article => article.eanCode === eanCodeOfNeededArticle);
```

But I Always get these error: Type 'Article[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Article': skuNumber, condition, eanCode, manufacturer, and 8 more

Can anyone help me? Thank you very much!

Comment: FYI you can put access modifiers on your constructor arguments.  `skuNumber: number` becomes `private skuNumber: number` and then `this.skuNumber = skuNumber` is generated by the transpiler so you don't have to manually do it for each variable.

Comment: Ah that's great to know! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filter` returns an array according to the condition. If you want only one result, you can use `find` instead of `filter`:

```
let article: Article = this.articles.find(article => article.eanCode === eanCodeOfNeededArticle);
```

---

array.filter: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

array.find: https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped.